# 'variable' is not a valid template argument for type 'pointer to member function'

Tags: c++, templates

I'm pretty new to both C++ and templates, and I'm trying to adapt a helper class that can be used to make delegates from member functions.

I changed this code (which compiles):

```
Delegate<void, int, int>* cheaty(void (Renderer::*method)(int, int), Renderer* obj)
    {
         auto maker = DelegateMaker<Renderer, void, int, int>();
         return maker.BindPointer<&Renderer::MoveCamera>(obj);
    }
```

To this:

```
 Delegate<void, int, int>* cheaty(void (Renderer::*method)(int, int), Renderer* obj)
    {
         auto maker = DelegateMaker<Renderer, void, int, int>();
         return maker.BindPointer<method>(obj);
    }
```

Which doesn't compile and gives the following error: `error: 'method' is not a valid template argument for type 'void (Engine::Renderer::*)(int, int)'`. Is what I am trying to achieve simply impossible because of limitations in C++ templates? Or am I just missing something really obvious?

Edit: 
Ideally, what I'd like to have is a function like this:

```
    template<typename T, typename return_type, typename... params>
    Delegate<return_type, params...>*   make_delegate_pointer(return_type (T::*name)(params...), T* obj)
    {
        DelegateMaker<T, return_type, params...> maker = DelegateMaker<T, return_type, params...>();
        return maker.BindPointer<name>(obj);
    }
```

And then call it like this `auto delegate = Delegates::make_delegate_pointer(&Class::Method, &classInstance);` Only, the problem I keep running into is the fact that there seems to be some difference between calling BindPointer like this `maker.BindPointer<&Class::Method>(classInstance);` and calling it like this `maker.BindPointer<return_type (Class::*)(arguments...)>(classInstance);`.

However, `return_type (T::*)(params...) memberFuncPointer = &Class::Method` compiles fine. Which means that logically, `maker.BindPointer<return_type (T::*)(params...)>(classInstance)` should compile as well (or some variation on that, which is why in the orginal question I attempted to use `method` as `void (Renderer::*method)(int, int)`). But it doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Template parameter values must be known at compile-time, but your `method` value is not known until runtime since `cheaty()` does not know which method of `Renderer` is being passed to it.  Thus the compiler error.  You will have to change `BindPointer` to not use a template anymore.  Besides, `DelegateMaker` already knows the method signature, so you do not need to duplicate that information as template parameters in `BindPointer()`, let it inherit the values from `DelegateMaker`.

For example (untested, might need some tweaking, but you should get the general idea):

```
template <typename ReturnType, typename... ParamTypes>
class Delegate
{
public:
    virtual ReturnType Invoke(ParamTypes... params) = 0;
};

template <typename ClassType, typename ReturnType, typename... ParamTypes>
class DelegateMaker
{
public:
    typedef ReturnType (ClassType::*MethodType)(ParamTypes... params);

private:
    class DelegateImpl : public Delegate<ReturnType, ParamTypes...> 
    {
    private:
        ClassType* _obj;
        MethodType _method;

    public:
        DelegateImpl(ClassType *obj, MethodType method)
            : _obj(obj), _method(method)
        {
        }

        virtual ReturnType Invoke(ParamTypes... params)
        {
            return (_obj.*_method)(params);
        }
    };

public:
    Delegate<ReturnType, ParamTypes...>* BindPointer(MethodType method, ClassType *obj)
    {
        return new DelegateImpl(obj, method);
    }
};
```

```
template <typename ClassType, typename ReturnType, typename... ParamTypes>
Delegate<ReturnType, ParamTypes...>* make_delegate_pointer(
    DelegateMaker<ClassType, ReturnType, ParamTypes...>::MethodType method,
    ClassType* obj)
{
    DelegateMaker<ClassType, ReturnType, ParamTypes...> maker;
    return maker.BindPointer(method, obj);
}
```

```
auto delegate = Delegates::make_delegate_pointer(&Class::Method, &classInstance);
```

Comment: Please see the edit to my question. While I understand that those values must be know at compile time, I don't see how the compiler can't resolve that. Because it is know at compile time, in the form of the method parameter. And does it matter exactly what method of renderer is passed to it? Shouldn't the method just fit in the pattern `void (Renderer::)(int, int)`?

Comment: No, the value of `method` is *not* known at compile time, that is the problem. It is a *runtime* value. Imagine if you have 2+ `Renderer` methods that you pass to `cheaty()`, eg: `cheaty(&Renderer::DoThis, SomeRendererObject); cheaty(&Renderer::DoThat, SomeRendererObject);`.  `cheaty()` is not itself a template function, so the compiler cannot create different versions of it based on which method is passed at compile-time. All `cheaty()` is being given is a pair of memory addresses that cannot be determined at compile-time, only at run-time.

Comment: Okay, but isn't it the type of `method` that should be used, instead of the value of `method`? In the case of `cheaty` it being `void (Renderer::*)(int, int). Because if `Renderer::DoThis` and `Renderer::DoThat` have the same return type, parameters and are member functions of the class `Renderer`. `Renderer::DoThis` and `Renderer::DoThat` have the same type (`void (Renderer::*)(int, int)`). Which is used for the templating, right?

Comment: The `method` parameter is a *pointer*, not a *type*. It has a *type* that the compiler uses to make sure you cannot pass an incompatible class method to `cheaty()`. But the *value* of `method` is a runtime pointer. That is why the *value* of `method` cannot be used as a template parameter at compile-time. However, you might try using `decltype(method)` as a template parameter, and pass the *value* of `method` as an input parameter so the delegate can use that value with the `.*` operator.

Comment: Okay, very stupid of me to miss that. I had a look at the code in your answer and used that fix the issue. So thanks a lot!